# array php loop. Difficult array. Make a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

really need your help with this array :

```
   Array
(
    [status] => 200
    [error] => 
    [resource] => Array
        (
            [type] => stats
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => Array
                                (
                                    [year] => 2015
                                    [month] => 12
                                )

                            [currency] => USD
                            [stats] => Array
                                (
                                    [count] => 2
                                    [total] => 2.53
                                    [average] => 1.265
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => Array
                                (
                                    [year] => 2016
                                    [month] => 1
                                )

                            [currency] => USD
                            [stats] => Array
                                (
                                    [count] => 2
                                    [total] => 15
                                    [average] => 7.5
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => Array
                                (
                                    [year] => 2016
                                    [month] => 1
                                )

                            [currency] => AUD
                            [stats] => Array
                                (
                                    [count] => 1
                                    [total] => 15
                                    [average] => 15
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => Array
                                (
                                    [year] => 2016
                                    [month] => 2
                                )

                            [currency] => AUD
                            [stats] => Array
                                (
                                    [count] => 7
                                    [total] => 1419.02
                                    [average] => 202.71714285714
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => Array
                                (
                                    [year] => 2016
                                    [month] => 2
                                )

                            [currency] => USD
                            [stats] => Array
                                (
                                    [count] => 8
                                    [total] => 2186.4
                                    [average] => 273.3
                                )

                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => Array
                                (
                                    [year] => 2016
                                    [month] => 3
                                )

                            [currency] => USD
                            [stats] => Array
                                (
                                    [count] => 3
                                    [total] => 865
                                    [average] => 288.33333333333
                                )

                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => Array
                                (
                                    [year] => 2016
                                    [month] => 3
                                )

                            [currency] => AUD
                            [stats] => Array
                                (
                                    [count] => 19
                                    [total] => 127279
                                    [average] => 6698.8947368421
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How i can get $value of [month] in the loop??

Help me please!

Comment: Both answers down here are good, depends what you want to do further with the **'month'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you're trying to access the "month" index within date?

If so, you could try something like this:

Let's say $array is your array.

```
foreach($array['resource']['data'] as $data) {
   echo $data['date']['month']; // Prints every month.
   echo "<br/>";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try `array_column` function (available since PHP 5.5)

```
// $arr is the initial array
$months = array_column($arr, 'month');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php